# Split the string by lower roman after colon and append to HTML

Tags: java, android, html, string, split

I am trying to split the String dynamically ,My string is as follows:

```
I need to call 2 numbers: (i) 1234 (ii) 4567
```

Sometimes my data might contain like this also:

```
1st type:

I need to call 2 numbers: numbers are (i) 1234 (ii) 4567 

2nd type:

I need to call my friends: numbers are as follows(only close friends)
```

i need to dispaly the data like this:

```
I need to call 2 numbers: 
(i) 1234 
(ii) 4567
```

that means after colon get the lower roman (i) and display it in next line, next get the (ii) lower roman and display it in next line and so on.

Now i am using regx to check if my String contains colon(:), if its there then get the pattern matching the regx and display.

It works fine for my initial case but for the 2 types which i have mention it will not work.

This is my code:

```
if(mString.contains(":")){
                     String [] parts = mString.split (":");

                     html.append("<p>"+parts [0]+"</p>");
                     Matcher m = Pattern.compile ("\\([^)]+\\)[^(]*").matcher (parts [1]);
                     while (m.find ()) {

                         html.append("<p>"+m.group ()+"<br>");
                     }
                     html.append("</br></p>");
```

EDIT:

```
I need to call 2 numbers: 
    (i) 1234 // it can be alphabets also like abc
    (ii) 4567 // it can be alphabets also abc
```

and also the lower romans can be n like (i),(ii),(iii) and so on

Comment: Are they always 4 digit numbers and are they the only 4 digit numbers that can appear in the string?

Comment: it not about the numbers sometimes it can be string also

Comment: How about replacing `(1` with `\n(1`

Comment: @Simon  can you explain me or give any example?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this code can help you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*:.*([0-9]{4}).*([0-9]{4}).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("I need to call 2 numbers: (i) 1234 (ii) 4567");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Anyway you could always use a subtring and indexOf,

Comment: if its string like this (i)abc (ii)ccc (iii)gggg i mean it can be string or numbers also, how to go about that?

Comment: and now its only 2 lines what if it has 3 or n lower numbers? please help me

Comment: you need to post the kind of inputs you are gonna get in order to make a regular expression.

Comment: please see my edit and help me to acheive i am stuck from long time

Comment: can you pleas help me? to acheive this?